# Checkbox to have a value when checked and another when unchecked

Tags: forms, post, checkbox, send

I have a form with:

```
Check this if you Want to receive our newsletter: <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter " name="newsletter">
```

I’m submitting it via a javascript/jquery function.

In the  js file, inside the submit function, I’m getting the value:

```
var newsletter = $("#newsletter").val();
```

And with the rest of the fom’s values goes with $.ajax  by POST to my php file.

The problem: the value of newsletter is “on” all the time.

How can I get a value if the checkbox is checked and another value if it’s unchecked?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To probe if checkbox is on or off use `.attr('checked')`:

```
var newsletter = $("#newsletter").attr('checked') ? "on" : "off";
```

Which will give you `'on'` for checked and `'off'` for unchecked.